# Not able to save screenshot in klov reporter. (Extent Reports)

Tags: c#, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am using both `HtmlReporter` and `KlovReporter` for my C-Sharp project. The issue here is, when i try to capture a screenshot in report it is not being saved and visible in klov reporter. But, i can see the screenshot being displayed in `HtmlReporter`. I'm receiving the below exception.

`System.UriFormatException:` 'Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.'

**Error:**

[image]

**HtmlReporter:** Screenshot is visible

[image]

**KlovReporter:** Screenshot is not visible

[image]

Please help me in identifying the issue here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: These issues are fixed with API version 3.1.2 and Klov 0.1.0.

Comment: I have updated my extent reports dependency to 3.1.2, and it worked well :)

Comment: @Anshoo can you please add your comments as an answer? i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These issues are fixed with API version 3.1.2 and Klov 0.1.0.